# iSGL3D Occlusion Culling

Tags: 3d, iphone, performance, culling, occlusion

I was testing a cool 3D Scene Graph Library called [iSGL3D](http://isgl3d.com). Since I found some functions called alpha culling for displaying partly hidden objects (making the ones in front transparent). I was wondering if it's possible to also do dynamic occlusion culling.

I know there are several descriptions for that like View Frustum Culling, Hidden Surface Detection, Hidden Surface Removal, but I can't find anything with google or on their homepage.

Comment: Are you asking how to do occlusion culling using iSGL3D, or are you asking if iSGL3D has any existing methods that do occlusion culling for you?

Comment: If it has Occlusing Culling methods how to use them.